# How to delay evaluation of knockout binding of element until data returns from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, fancytree

I'm using Durandal and Knockout.

In my html I have

```
<div id="fancytree-users" data-bind="fancytree: userlist"></div>
```

I have a custom binding as so:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.fancytree = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var tm = valueAccessor();
            var tmUnwrapped = tm();
            $(element).fancytree({
                minExpandLevel: 1,
                source: tmUnwrapped,
            })
        }
```

In my "attached" event I do

```
initTree();
```

Which is:

```
        return dc.getUserList()
        .then(function (data) {
            self.userlist(tv.loadUserTree(data, userTreeData));
        })
```

And the method it calls is:

```
var getUserList = function () {

    return $.getJSON("/api/admin/getUsers", {})
        .done(function (data) {
            return data;
        })
};
```

But it appears I have a race condition. If I put debugs in my bindinghandler then 9 times out of 10 it hits that before it returns data from my ajax call. As there is nothing in the `valueAccessor` parameter at that point, this results in nothing appearing in my treeview. The other 1 time out of 10 it works and the treeview looks fine.

How can I force my UI to wait until the `userlist` observableArray is filled before it evaluates the custom binding?

Comment: A quick and dirty fix might be to wrap the element in an `if: userList().length` binding. Once the `userList` observable gets filled with items, knockout will include the custom bound element and apply bindings.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about "if:..."  I just put it in there and it works fine. Well, it appears to work fine for now!  I don't think it's just my database running quickly all of a sudden.  I may add in an artificial delay of a few seconds just to double check. Not sure if it's best practise or not, but works for me, thanks.

Comment: The `if` binding controls descendant bindings, meaning that it will (re)apply bindings, calling `init`. Ideally, your custom bindings handle missing data/refreshes without being dependant on wrappers/other stuff. I'd suggest looking at some of the examples to see how you can recreate and dispose widgets once data changes.

Comment: Perfect. Just tested it with a cheeky `setTimeout` of 5 seconds and everything loaded and then after another 5 seconds, the tree appeared.  Add it as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: The problem with the custom binding is that it is for a treeview that has hundreds of users in different categories. I don't want to make every field of the user object observable so the observable array realises something has changed when the userlist observablearray is populated. It's for an internal page admin page anyway, so this will do fine.